# Equaling max value in two side of graph in highcharts.js

Tags: javascript, graph, highcharts

Hello I am trying to show some data on highcharts.js it is working fine but I need to set max value of two side of graph because showing data with this way misleading user. Even value of line data is less than bar data it is still showing top side of bar because of line data's scale on right.

[image]

How can I avoid that ? How can I set same scale for both side of graph ?

Comment: To show them on the same scale just use one axis instead of two with a different scale. Could you reproduce this chart in an online code editor like jsfiddle?

Comment: Another option would be to manually set the min Y value to 0 and the max Y value to your highest value on both axis

Comment: @Weedoze I did it just like that. I compare the highest value of data arrays and set manually the highest value.

Comment: It is getting scale automatically @WojciechChmiel

Comment: @SuatKarabacak If you found an answer, please post your answer here and mark it as answered for future readers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I have 2 data arrays I compared max value of array's elements and manually set both graph's max value to this element.